Mixamo - Y up vs Z up
I just started experimenting with Mixamo in Blender and the up/forward orientations confuse me.
I added the Mixamo Control Rig to the character. If I look at the transforms, changing the Y location moves a control up and down. But in the viewport GZ moves the control up and down, so the viewport is using Z up.
I tried changing the fbx import settings to change the up axis, but that didn't help.
Am I missing something obvious?
Thanks for any tips.

yeah I have noticed that about .fbx files ..... have you found a work around ...have you tried correcting the origin and scale ... i did manage you use a character with auto rig pro ...
